# Почему не подвязываются файлы стилей и и др. в idea?

Tags: java, spring

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь подключить файлы стилей, лежат там же где и главный html файл, но они не подгружаются почему-то

Answer (score 2):

1. В папке resources создаем папку static и закидываем туда все что связано с css/js/img и тому подобное
2. Прописываем пути `<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/main.css">` и др.
3. В main метод добавляем блок:

```
@Configuration
    public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
        }
    }
```